# mk808b plus Android TV dongle not present as device in device manager, can't use for development

Tags: android, windows, usb, adb, device

I recently bought an android tv box (dongle) model mk808b plus which some of you might be familiar with. What I want to do is use it for development, I want to program on it using adb, Android Studio.

The problem I am facing and its not the first of its kind, I get this with all the media boxes that I tried, they dont work as adb devices at all, I dont get any device in my device manager when I connect them on the usb (not even an unknown one). I tried reflashing the android, I put cyanogen mod on it, but to no avail, it still happens. Another thing is, if I put my device in Recovery Mode it does detect an unknown device in my control panel, but never after I boot up my android os.

Now before you say I didnt enable Developer Options Usb Debugging or I didnt put my device as MTP device, I did. I checked these and the cables im using are fine.

I dont have any problem with my Nexus 5 or S5 for the matter, just when I try these android boxes that come up with these tv like custom roms.

If you guys have any idea, I'll be happy to read, I did not find anything related to this on the internet.

PS: Why not use my Nexus 5 or S5? because the app im developing is for these boxes, so testing some of the features such as hdmi connectivity etc etc is very useful to me.

Thank you,
Andi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn't do anything, maybe it's because of the custom ROM on it, but I did find an alternative, I'm using adb on tcp ip, it seems to work after I rooted my device, still no usb adb interface.